# CORS-enable autobahn.asyncio.websocket server

Tags: python, websocket, cors

I create a local Python 3 server using autobahn.asyncio.websocket that talks to a JavaScript client in a local browser. In the client I want to fetch from the server jpegs to use as textures and font files to enable extruding 3D text. The browser window shows an address "file:///.....html", having been created in the Python server with webbrowser.open("file:///.....html"). I need to CORS-enable the server, and it looks like the way to do that is as follows:

factory = WebSocketServerFactory(u"ws://localhost:9000/")
factory.setProtocolOptions(allowedOrigins=['*'])

But I get an error "origin 'file://' not allowed".

How can I permit the client to read data files from the server?

Comment: A colleague may have shown me a way out: use an ordinary mechanism for part of the job, including serving image and font files, and a websocket mechanism on a different port for the needed rapid two-way communication that I need.

Comment: I implemented a very simple HTTP server (port 9000), and an autobahn.asyncio.websocket mechanism on a different port (port 9001) to handle rapid 2-way communications between server and client. I open a web page with webbrowser.open('http://localhost:9000) and the server transmits an html file that includes JavaScript websocket code for port 9001. There is no CORS issue because getting image files takes place in the 9000 domain. In the server I run both the server and the websocket "run-forever" functions inside threads, to enable the user program that imports this Python module to run.